# Using Verify to confirm expected parameter values in Moq mock class

Tags: nunit, moq, autofixture

I'm trying to verify that a method within a mock is called with an expected object parameter.  I'm using Moq, nUnit, and thinking that AutoFixture's Likeness should get the job done.
Below is a simplified version of what i'm trying to do.

Is there a way to do this with AutoFixture?  Is there a better way to verify that `Something` is called with the appropriate parameter?

Overriding Equals in the `A` class to compare the property values and changing the `Verify` line to:

```
barMock.Verify(m => m.Something(a));
```

passes, however I'd rather not override Equals in every class like A in my project.

```
namespace Test
{
    using Moq;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using Ploeh.SemanticComparison.Fluent;

    public class A
    {
        public int P1 { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IBar
    {
        void Something(A a);
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public A Data { get; private set; }
        public void DoSomethingWith(IBar bar)
        {
            Data = new A { P1 = 1 };
            bar.Something(Data);
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class AutoFixtureTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestSample()
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            var barMock = new Mock<IBar>();
            var a = new A { P1 = 1 };
            var expectedA = a.AsSource().OfLikeness<A>();

            foo.DoSomethingWith(barMock.Object);

            expectedA.ShouldEqual(foo.Data);   // passes
            barMock.Verify(m => m.Something(expectedA.Value));  // fails
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In `Verify` Moq by default checks reference equality for arguments so it only passes when you provide the same instances (except if you've overriden `Equals`) in your tests and in your implementation.

In you case the `expectedA.Value` just returns the `new A { P1 = 1 }` created in the test which, of course, isn't the same instance created in `DoSomethingWith`.

You need to use Moq's `It.Is` construct to properly test this without overriding `Equals` (in fact for this you don't need Autofixture at all):

```
barMock.Verify(m => m.Something(It.Is<A>(arg => arg.P1 == a.P1)));
```

But if you have multiple properties like P1,P2,P3... AutoFixture can be useful:

```
barMock.Verify(m => m.Something(It.Is<A>(arg => expectedA.Equals(a))));
```

Because you don't need to write out the equality checks manually for all the properties.

Comment: +1 Particularly the last solution is the correct approach with Likeness. FWIW there's a work item for a new functionality for Likeness to enable it to dynamically emit a proxy that overrides Equals, which would greatly simplify the above syntax: http://autofixture.codeplex.com/workitem/4230

Answer (score 5):

If you upgrade to AutoFixture 2.9.1 (or newer) you can call the CreateProxy method on the Likeness instance which will emit a dynamic proxy for the destination type.

The generated dynamic proxy overrides Equals using Likeness which simplifies the syntax (quite a lot).

Here is the original test method, modified to use the Likeness proxy:

```
[Test]
public void TestSample()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    var barMock = new Mock<IBar>();
    var expected = new A().AsSource().OfLikeness<A>().CreateProxy();
    expected.P1 = 1;

    foo.DoSomethingWith(barMock.Object);

    Assert.True(expected.Equals(foo.Data));     // passes
    barMock.Verify(m => m.Something(expected)); // passes
}
```

Note that it also makes the test assertion much more specific than accepting *Any* instance.

You can find more details on this new feature [here](http://www.nikosbaxevanis.com/bonus-bits/2012/02/dynamic-proxy-overriding-equals-in-autofixture-likeness.html).